# How to detect wether or not a string is a pangram and return true or false

Tags: ruby, methods, pangram

A pangram is a sentence that contains every single letter of the alphabet at least once. For example, the sentence "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" is a pangram, because it uses the letters A-Z at least once (case is irrelevant). I'm trying to make a method that takes a string and returns true or false for if it is a pangram. This is what I tried so far.

```
def pangram?(string)
  letters = string.chars.downcase.uniq
  letters.uniq.all? {|c| string.count(c)==26}
end

def pangram?(string)
  string.downcase
  ("a".."z").all?{|c| string.count(c) <= 1}
end
```

Any better suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your second example `string.downcase` does not change original string. Use `#downcase!`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could go with something like:

```
s.downcase.scan(/[a-z]/).uniq.size == 26
```

This downcases the String scans for all characters "a" through "z" and checks that the uniq size of these characters equals 26.

*Issues with your Current solutions*

The first one will never work as is

1. `chars` returns an `Array` and `Array#downcase` is not a method
2. You are checking that each letter in the original string occurs 26 times  (`string.count(c)==26`) so `'a' * 26` will pass this test but "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" will not.

The second has issues too:

1. the first line serves no purpose. It downcases the string and disposes of the result
2. `String#count` is going to be inefficient;
3. `''` will pass this test as each letter occurs 0 times. e.g. `<= 1` times.

Answer (score 1):

```
def pangram?(string)
  (("a".."z").to_a - string.downcase.chars).empty?
end
```

Comment: ...or `a = ("a".."z").to_a; a & string.downcase.chars == a` (but prefer what you have).

Comment: @CarySwoveland `a = [*('a'..'z')] and a.&(string.downcase.chars).size == a.size`

Comment: engineersmnky That works. Cary Swoveland Sorry, that works, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @ChiaraAni `&` is `Array#intersection` it will return all the elements present in the original array and the argument array(s) e.g. `["b","c"] & ["c"] #=> ["c"]`. In Cary's example the intersection must be equivalent to the original for the case to be true. This works because order of the original is preserved during intersection

Comment: Why don't you add them as answers?

Comment: @ChiaraAni because it's just for fun. Like this one `('a'..'z').then {|a| a.to_a - string.downcase.chars}.empty?`

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'set'
```

```
def pangram?(str)
  str.downcase.each_char.with_object(('a'..'z').to_set) {|c,st| st.delete(c)}.empty?
end
```

```
pangram?("The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox")          #=> true
pangram?("The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fo.")          #=> false
pangram?("The quick brown dog, Saffi, jumps over the lazy fox.") #=> true
```

I've converted `'a'..'z'` to a set rather than an array merely to speed calculations.

If the strings are long it may be faster to return `true` as soon as 26 distinct characters are found:

```
def pangram?(str)
  str.downcase.each_char.with_object(('a'..'z').to_set) do |c,st|
    st.delete(c)
    return true if s.empty?
  end
  false
end
```

Comment: @engineersmnky, yes, I considered that, and did the edit, but changed my mind before saving. I'll mention it.